# MIPS - Load integer into array - store address not aligned on word boundary

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

```
    .data

p1: .asciiz "\nEnter the data for a sorted array: "
p2: .asciiz "\nEnter a value to search for:  "
p3: .asciiz " is not found"
p4: .asciiz " is found at "
array:  .space 404

    .text

main:
    la  $t0, array  # a1 = addr of first int

#Store Array Values
store:
li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
la  $a0, p1     # address of string to print
syscall         # print the first prompt
li  $v0, 5      # system call for read_int
syscall         # read int to store
move    $t1, $v0    # store int
beq $t1, 0, bsearch # once sentinel val hit, go to search
sub $t9, $t0, 4 # set index to the first bit of the last number
j   storeVal    # store s0 in array

storeVal:
    sw  $t1, array($t0) # store value in array
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4 # inc index
    j   store       # continue to add integers

#Binary Search
bsearch:

    li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
    la  $a0, p2     # address of string to print
    syscall         # print the second prompt
    li  $v0, 5      # system call for read_int
    syscall         # read int to find
    move    $a0, $v0    # store int to find
    beq $a0, 0, end # once sentinel val hit, go to end prog
    la  $a2, array  # a1 = addr of first int
    la  $a2, ($t9)  # a2 = addr of last int
    subu    $sp, $sp, 4 # 4 bytes 4 stack
    sw  $ra, 4($sp) # save return addr

    subu    $t0, $t9, $s0   # size of array
    bnez    $t0, searchVal  # if not 0, search

    move    $v0, $a1    # addr of only entry
    lw  $t0, ($v0)  # load entry
    beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
    j   notFound    # not found

searchVal:

    sra $t0, $t0, 3 # comp offset of middle m:
    sll $t0, $t0, 2 # t0 = 4(t1/8)
    addu    $v0, $a1, $t0   # middle m
    lw  $t0, ($v0)  # t0 = m
    beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
    blt $a0, $t0, left  # search left
    j   right       # search right

right:

    addu    $a1, $v0, 4 # search right
    jal bsearch
    beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
    j   notFound    # not found

left:

    move    $a2, $v0    # search left of m
    jal     bsearch
    beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
    j   notFound    # not found

#Print
found:

    li  $v0, 1      # system call code for print_int
    move    $a0, $s2    # integer to print (counter
    syscall         # print it

    li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
    la  $a0, p4     # address of string to print
    syscall         # print the answer part 2

    j   bsearch     # continue to search for more integers

notFound:

    li  $v0, 1      # system call code for print_int
    move    $a0, $s2    # integer to print (counter)
    syscall         # print it

    li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
    la  $a0, p3     # address of string to print
    syscall         # print the answer part 2

    j   bsearch     # continue to search for more integers

#END PROG
end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I keep getting an error when I attempt to load words into my array, "Error in /../Proj.asm line 58: Runtime exception at 0x00400040: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x200200c2.

```
57) storeVal:
    58) sw  $t1, array($t0) # store value in array
    59) addi    $t0, $t0, 4 # inc index
    60) j   store       # continue to add integers
```

Line 58 being the sw $t1, array($t0) one. I have tried setting t0 (the line right after .main) the way shown, and setting it to $zero with

```
addi $t1, $zero, 0
```

neither of the options will let me set an item into the array, and I cannot find a guide or tutorial to save my life... Also while we're at it, can anyone see if the rest of the code is at least close? Thanks!

Comment: Even if that would save your life, I refuse to count to line 58. Can you extract the part of the code where it happens?

Comment: My posting skills are very subpar, the formatting is something I haven't grasped yet. Let me know if this looks better and is easier to understand.